# Reading Password-Protected ZIP Files in Java

Tags: java, encryption, compression, zip

I have zipped and protected a file with a password.
Now I need to retrieve the file back with java. So I need to unlock the password and unzip with Java to make a proper connection to the file.

My first Questions is: Does Java unzip and unlock the zipped file on the local drive? (So no point protecting it?).

I have read all about encryption, but really searching for the easiest way here.
This link: http://blog.alutam.com/2009/10/31/reading-password-protected-zip-files-in-java/

My second Question is about the link above: I cannot find the lines where he is pointing to his zipped file on the local drive+ the password he uses to unlock the file (is it hardcoded?)

Thank you

Comment: _I cannot find the lines where he is pointing to his zipped file on the local drive+ the password he uses to unlock the file (is it hardcoded?)_ No. As you can see, he uses `args[0]` and `args[1]`. It means that he is taking the zip file path and its password from command line arguments

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look on [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)

**Key features:**

1. Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
2. Read/Write password protected Zip files
3. Supports AES 128/256 Encryption
4. Supports Standard Zip Encryption
5. Supports Zip64 format
6. Supports Store (No Compression) and Deflate compression method
7. Create or extract files from Split Zip files (Ex: z01, z02,...zip)
8. Supports Unicode file names
9. Progress Monitor

Comment: Well Zip4J is a great tool. But the problem is that it extracts the zipped file somewhere on my local drive. So it is not encrypted anymore. I don't see the point of zipping it, if Java needs to unzip it to reach the file..

Comment: @RobinHo You are missing the point. A zip is a compressed archive, of course you need to decompress it to read files within it. If you just want a list of the files it contains, then there is no need to decompress, but if you want to read you have to decompress the file.

Comment: well you can create a list of files and take everything(content) in one inputstream. Now read on and close it once you are done. There is one option getInputStream() that converts it to a stream.